# Which string concatenation is best for performance Pair<String, String> vs StringBuilder vs + operator

Tags: java, string-concatenation, apache-commons

I am new to using Apache Commons pair. I need some advice what the best approach is when performance and optimization is priority.

If I want to concatenate str1 and str2, I can choose from the following approaches

**StringBuilder**

```
String newStr = (new StringBuilder()).append(str1).append(str2).toString();
```

**+ operator**

```
String newStr = str1 + str2;
```

**Apache Commons Pair<String, String>**

```
Pair<String, String> key = Pair.of(str1, str2);
key.getLeft() + key.getRight() // this just ends up needing to use a concatenation operator
```

So I thought, maybe `StringBuilder` would be best?

The newStr is not within a loop. A colleague told me about possible HeapMemory issue when Strings are stored at runtime.

Comment: Just use the `+` operator. `StringBuilder` is really only helpful when concatenating inside a loop. Making a `Pair` object is needless overhead also.

Comment: Note if you use Java 9 and later, the compilers do a better job of optimizing string concatenations.  So if you are concerned in performance your best option is to upgrade to Java 11 or Java 17 ... so that you don't need to mess up your code-base with micro-optimizations ... that may then need to be undone.  (Java 8 is obsolete, and in some contexts it is "end of life".)

Comment: You don't provide enough context. Is this a one-off operation? Is it in a loop? Of-course, a [mcve] would help provide that context. Usually, however, using the `+` operator is the best (in terms of performance).

Comment: I'm curious to know why you would even consider the third option, that makes no sense, and is identical to the second option, except you needlessly create an additional object (a `Pair`).

Answer (score 0):

The + operator is always going to be better than the other options you've shown.  Depending on context, it might still be appropriate to use `StringBuilder`, but not in the way you've shown.